# wrong version of sqlite3 required for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am trying to do a new ruby on rails, everything goes perfectly until it want to install sqlite3 - I do have it installed and it is recognised when asking it in cmd, but the error asks for a different version. Tried to install that version, but no success. 
I tried many other things from the internet, but just can't make it work.
I am a newbie trying to learn.

Installing sqlite3 1.4.0 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0/ext/sqlite3
C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20190308-12720-15tc5du.rb extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for pthread_create() in -lpthread... yes
checking for -ldl... no
checking for dlopen()... no
missing function dlopen
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-config
        --without-sqlite3-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-dir
        --without-sqlite3-dir
        --with-sqlite3-include
        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
        --with-sqlite3-lib
        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
        --with-pthreadlib
        --without-pthreadlib
        --with-dllib
        --without-dllib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  sqlite3

**installing the required version**

gem install sqlite3 -v 1.4.0
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Installing required msys2 packages: mingw-w64-x86_64-sqlite3
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0/ext/sqlite3
```

C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20190308-5276-1djiqig.rb extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for pthread_create() in -lpthread... yes
checking for -ldl... no
checking for dlopen()... no
missing function dlopen
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-config
        --without-sqlite3-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-dir
        --without-sqlite3-dir
        --with-sqlite3-include
        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
        --with-sqlite3-lib
        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
        --with-pthreadlib
        --without-pthreadlib
        --with-dllib
        --without-dllib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/gem_make.out

Comment: You can really skip sqlite altogether and use rails with Postgres or MySql. The only reason rails defaults to sqlite is that its a relatively easy to setup (on Linux and OS-X) so that you can get it up and running quickly for development. You're not actually going to be deploying rails applications with Sqlite as it does not scale so it makes sense to develop and test on the database you are actually going to use.

Comment: That said I would really recommend that you use virtualbox to setup a virtual machine running Linux as most rails tutorials assume that you are using a Posix compliant OS and you'll will struggle needlessly with setup issues on windows. Also you will most likely not be deploying to a windows server unless you really don't like your life. https://guides.railsgirls.com/virtual-machine

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some issues with new sqlite 1.4.0 gem.
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/35153

Use this version instead.
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6'

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.
After all I followed Max's proposal I changed to postgres and is working perfectly.